# Calling an Oracle function with parameters, returning a table, from .NET

Tags: .net, oracle10g

In PL/SQL I can make this query to return a table of record from my function:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(MyPackage.get_some_values('arg1', 'arg2'));
```

How should I execute this from .NET?

a) If I pass the above as is as a **CommandText**, then I get a Message = "ORA-00911: invalid character" error.

b) Ideally though, I want to pass a **CommandText** and then a set of **Parameters** to the execution context.

Comment: What happens if you pass the above command (as you already did in **a)**), but omit the final semi-colon (`;`)? I don't know .net, but - in Oracle dynamic SQL (which also accepts a command it should execute), you can't terminate the statement with a semi-colon, as Oracle raises the same ORA-00911 error. So, if there's any similarity between those two, ...

Comment: Awesome! That was it! I was looking at the wrong place obviously. That takes care of a), do you know how to implement b)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no; as I said, I don't know .net.